# Curious DllImport issue, when passing a LONG parameter memory corruption

Tags: c#, c++, .net-3.5, dllimport

I've created a DLL function for using inside C# using DLLImport but having troubles in calling the method, as I'm getting memory corruption problems;

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "callinmydll")]
public static extern int testdllcall(double *firstinput, long firstcount, double *secondoutput, long secondcount);
```

Here's part of the C++ library header;

```
extern "C" {              

mydll_API int callinmydll(double *in, long firstcount, double *out, long secondcount);

}
```

Implementation.

```
mydll_API int callinmydll(double *in, long firstcount, double *out, long secondcount)
{
    for( int i =0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) 
    {
        *(out + i) = (*(in + i) + 10 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now when my DLLImport function calls the callinmydll function and passes valid data to it, this is where things get interesting.  The pointer *in contains data, as does firstcount.  Although everything beyond this point is corrupted.  Why?  Curiously I rearrange my function to be double*, double*, long, long now the corruption happens after third parameter.  I'm curious as to what's going on, as I'm passing valid data; two valid pointers, and int cast to int64.

Help!

Comment: Not really sure but isn't a long in c++ more like an int in c# i.e. -2147483647 to 2147483647

Comment: The calling conventions also do not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Win32 C, a `long` is still 32-bits. Your C# signature is using a `long` which is 64-bits. Your second and forth parameter should be an `int` in the C# signature.

See this [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx) for more information.

So your signature looks like so:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "callinmydll")]
public static extern int testdllcall(double *firstinput, int firstcount, double *secondoutput, int secondcount);
```

Additionally, make sure your calling convention is correct as Ramhound pointed out in the comments. Your C function looks like it is using the CDecl convention, and .NET defaults to StdCall. You can set the calling convention in the attribute:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "callinmydll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Comment: If the managed code is intended to run in either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows environments, then how should one marshal a LONG parameter?

Comment: Assuming "LONG" means Win32 long, it should be marshaled as an `int`.